# ConcatRelated function

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

i got error when using ConcatRelated http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

my data looks like:

[image]

[image]

want this result clocking time right hand side

using this

```
SELECT ConcatRelated("Clocking Time"
                   , "ClockingQuery"
                   , "Patrol Time = ' "& [Patrol Time] & "'") AS Clock
FROM ClockingQuery;
```

got error

how to do?

ms-access sql concatrelation concatenate

Comment: "got error" -- what error?

Answer (score 0):

You must use properly formatted string expression for the date values, and avoid spaces and/or typos in field names:

```
SELECT 
    ConcatRelated("ClockingTime", "ClockingQuery", "[Patrol Time] = #" & Format([Patrol Time], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#") AS Clock 
FROM 
    ClockingQuery;
```